# Is there a recursive formula for adding vectors based on their angle to find their position?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, recurrence-relations, vector-analysis, trigonometric-series

Given X amount of vectors, and their respective angle and length, how can I find the respective position? I have uploaded an image example for reference

[example using 4 vectors]
ab length = 4
bc length = 8
cd length = 16
de length = 8

NOTE: the angle is the angle at which the following vector is shifting from its previous point.
angle b = 20
angle c = 0
angle d = 270

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXv5r.jpg)

Comment: Use coordinates.

Comment: I will always know the coordinates to point A and B, I know how to manually compute the coordinates for point C from its respective input angle, but I don't know how to add the vectors after C, then after D, and so on for however many vectors are needed.

Comment: @MistyMoon: Use coordinates and formally state the process: label the starting point as origin O$(0,0)$ and use vector resolution to calculate the destination point coordinates given length $d_i$ and traversal angle $\theta_i$ relative to the horizontal given by the previous traversal: it is simply translation by $(d_i\cos\theta_i,d_i\sin\theta_i)$